# Как получить несколько писем через один запрос?

Tags: email, gmail

Я пользуюсь Gmail API для получения писем с почты пользователя — всё нормально, всё получается. Для получения всех писем нужно посылать запросы: для 100 писем — 100 запросов. Это, наверное, перегружает сервер, и я начал искать другой способ, но пока ничего не нашёл; решил обратился к вам.

Есть способы получения нескольких писем через один запрос?

Код получения ID писем:

```
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
        'userId': "me",
        'labelIds': labelID,
        'maxResults': 10
    });
```

Код получения самих писем:

```
return gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
    'userId': "me",
    'id': messageID
});
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А поконкретнее нельзя? Привести, например, код для извлечения писем, обращение к API? (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Добавил

Comment: Думаю никак, API не предоставляет механизм для этого. Но в пользу вас, не думаю что вы достигнете лимита если у вас не миллионы сообщений (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov А для чего Batch предназначен? ( https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch )

Answer (score 0):

Вы правы, можно использовать batch для извлечения списка сообщений как указано в https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync под пунктом Full synchronization. Но так как для вас будет трудозатратно воссоздать это в Javascript'е, я нашел решение по поиску [SU](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgmail-api%5D%20batch%20javascript) [здесь](https://github.com/emiltholin/google-api-batch-utils). Для того чтобы получить первые три сообщения из ящика там есть готовый пример:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var batchUtils = require('google-api-batch-utils');
var createBatchBody = batchUtils.createBatchBody;
var parseBatchResponse = batchUtils.parseBatchResponse;

var BOUNDARY = 'example_boundary';

rp({
  uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages',
  qs: { maxResults: 3 , fields: 'messages(id)'},
  headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer {API_KEY}'},
  json: true
}).then(function(response) {
  var uris = response.messages.map(function(item) {
    return {uri: '/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/' + item.id, qs: { fields: 'snippet'}};
  });

  var batchBody = createBatchBody(uris, BOUNDARY);
  return rp({
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer {API_KEY}' ,
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + BOUNDARY + '"'
    },
    body: batchBody
  });
}).then(parseBatchResponse)
  .then(console.log.bind(console));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а есть какая то документация как им пользоваться?Я ничего не понял честно)